# how to get the html value of a brother div

Tags: php, jquery, increment, decrement

Im sorry for the title but i did not know how to frame a title for this question

Question:

i have a container div and two child divs.the first child div contains a numeric value which i want incremented every time the second child div is clicked

CODE:

```
 <div class="container1">
    <span class="like_counter">2</like>
    <span class="like_unlike">Like</span><!--if the text within is like then on click it will change the inner text to unlike and increment the value in like counter by 1.if it is unlike it will decrement it by 1 and change inner text to Like-->
 </div>
```

Note the first child selectors are not an option because it would affect every first child div

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes first-child it seemed plausible but the problem started when multiple divs were present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers, used `prev` function not very good, if the order of items changes, code stop working.

Try this:

```
$(".like_unlike").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var likeCounter = $(this).siblings(".like_counter");
    likeCounter.html(parseInt(likeCounter.html()) + 1);
});
```

Comment: solution seems solid but i need to get the value ie 2 from like counter and increment it

Comment: @Mr.coder, ok, answer corrected. On click to `.like_unlike`, counter incremented.

Comment: @Mr.coder you have rightly titled it to be a brother, for this case using a sibling would be a better call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(this).prev()
```

And some more interesting sibling searches along-with others are listed here http://home.techphernalia.com/70480/HTML/Selector.html

Answer (score 0):

It's called sibling. You can use

```
$(this).prev();
```

https://api.jquery.com/prev/